# Numpy: Uniform way of retrieving `dtype`

Tags: python, numpy

If I have a numpy array `x`, I can get its data type by using `dtype` like this:

```
t = x.dtype
```

However, that obviously won't work for things like lists. I wonder if there is a standard way of retrieving types for lists and numpy arrays. In the case of lists, I guess this would mean the largest type which fits all of the data. For instance, if

```
x = [ 1, 2.2 ]
```

I would want such a method to return `float`, or better yet `numpy.float64`.

Intuitively, I thought that this was the purpose of the `numpy.dtype` method. However, that is not the case. That method is used to *create* a type, not *extract* a type.

The only method that I know of getting a type is to wrap whatever object is passed in with a numpy array, and then get the `dtype`:

```
def dtype(x):
    return numpy.asarray(x).dtype
```

The issue with this approach, however, is that it will copy the array if it is not already a numpy array. In this circumstance, that is extremely heavy for such a simple operation.

So is there a `numpy` method that I can use which won't require me to do any list copies?

---

### EDIT

I am designing a library for doing some geometric manipulations... Conversions between rotation matrices, rotation vectors, quaternions, euler angles, etc.

It can easily happen that the user is simply working with a single rotation vector (which has 3 elements). In that case, they might write something like

```
q = vectorToQuaternion([ .1, 0, 0 ])
```

In this case, I would want the output quaternion to be a numpy array of type `numpy.float64`. However, sometimes to speed up the calculations, the user might want to use a numpy array of float32's:

```
q = vectorToQuaternion(numpy.float32([ .1, 0, 0 ]))
```

In which case, I think it is natural to expect that the output is the same type.

The issue is that I cannot use the `zeros_like` function (or `empty_like`, etc) because a quaternion has 4 components, while a vector has 3. So internally, I have to do something like

```
def vectorToQuaternion(v):
    q = empty( (4,), dtype = asarray(v).dtype )
    ...
```

If there was a way of using `empty_like` which extracts all of the properties of the input, but lets me specify the shape of the output, then that would be the ideal function for me. However, to my knowledge, you cannot specify the shape in the call to `empty_like`.

---

### EDIT

Here are some gists for the class I am talking about, and a test class (so that you can see how I intend to use it).

Class: https://gist.github.com/mholzel/c3af45562a56f2210270d9d1f292943a

Tests: https://gist.github.com/mholzel/1d59eecf1e77f21be7b8aadb37cc67f2

Comment: No, *lists are not typed*. A `dtype` is not something most Python objects have.

Comment: Why are you mixing numpy arrays and lists?

Comment: I understand that lists are not typed. As I state in the question, I would want behavior similar to what you would get with `numpy.asarray(x).dtype`, but without a copy

Comment: @Georgy Designing some library functions which could be passed a small list or a large array

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to allow both of the following: `func([1,2,3])` and `func(numpy.array([1,2,3]))`

Comment: What would require this?

Comment: Python lists should not be treated as equivalent to numpy arrays, if that requires a dtype notion. They are similar in that they are sequences, but that is about it. But again, where would you need to know this for a function? What *exactly* is your use-case?

Comment: The principle use case is that I want to do something like the `zeros_like` function, but where you could specify a different shape than the input

Comment: Why would that require a dtype?? Just use `0`. BTW, the function you are looking for is `np.zeros`

Comment: Question updated to provide more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do it that way you will probably have to use `np.asarray`, but I'm not sure that's the most solid way of dealing with the problem. If the user forgets to add `.` and gives `[1, 0, 0]` then you will be creating integer outputs, which most definitely does not make sense for quaternions. I would default to `np.float64`, using the `dtype` of the input if it is an array of some float type, and maybe also giving the option to explicitly pass a dtype:

```
import numpy as np

def vectorToQuaternion(v, dtype=None):
    if dtype is None:
        if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) and np.issubdtype(v.dtype, np.floating):
        # Or if you prefer:
        if np.issubdtype(getattr(v, 'dtype', np.int), np.floating):
            dtype = v.dtype
        else:
            dtype = np.float64
    q = np.empty((4,), dtype=dtype)
    # ...
```

Comment: As a side note, you may already be aware of it, but the package [`quaternion`](https://github.com/moble/quaternion) implements a good number of quaternion operations in NumPy.

Comment: A little backstory: I am porting a lot of code to generic numpy implementations

Comment: hopefully eventually including tensorflow

Comment: The problem is that I do not want to hardcode the numpy implementation, which would let you substitute out the numpy implementation easily. I will set up a gist in a second here so that you can see

Comment: Here is the rotations class: https://gist.github.com/mholzel/c3af45562a56f2210270d9d1f292943a

Comment: Here is the test class: https://gist.github.com/mholzel/1d59eecf1e77f21be7b8aadb37cc67f2

Comment: The difficulty using most standard python libraries is that they either use compiled code behind the scenes, or have the standard `numpy` implementation hardcoded. I want to be able to use such classes with autodifferentiation libraries (autograd, tensorflow, etc) for the purpose of optimization. So I need a library that lets you swap out the numpy implementation

Comment: @bremen_matt I think I understand what you mean... I actually had a similar problem, wanted to implement some algorithms in a way that I could use them for NumPy and TensorFlow. I ended up writing an `nptf` module that would use one or other "backend" depending on the input (or on your choice). I think a well-written, comprehensive package implementing that idea (a generic numerical library, possibly with more "backends") would be quite useful, although it's probably quite some work...

Comment: I am doing this for OpenCV

Comment: I have made quite  a bit of progress using this idea

Comment: The barrier with OpenCV is that it uses a ton of compiled code. So if you need to compute jacobians of those functions, you are stuck using numerical differentiation which results in large errors and compute time. I am making versions of many functions that use a generic numpy implementation. This would let you use autograd easily. Furthermore, I imagine that in many instances, you could get away with making a thin wrapper for Tensorflow and passing that as your "numpy" package